# How do I completely delete or change a custom field added to a base Acumatica page?

Tags: acumatica

I've struggled with this issue my entire Acumatica career. The customer asks for a custom field made for a base Acumatica page. They give me the data type of the field. I create said field. The customer decides to change the spec which in turn changes the type on the field. I change the field type in Data Access, but it doesn't work. I change the field type in every place I know to find it (Data Access Class, .XML, CustObjects), the field still contains the same properties! I delete the field completely, run a clean publish to make sure it gets wiped and recreate the field with the same name. Nope! Some how the old type still remains assigned to that field. I have even completely deleted the project, ran a clean publish, recreated the project with the same name, ran another clean while empty, recreated the DAC object with the same name, ran ANOTHER clean publish, and it STILL has the old control type despite not being set in the project XML or CustObjects table.

How do I change the field type of a Usr field created via the Data Access section of the Customization Project?

My current solution is I just append a 2 to the name, so it becomes UsrFieldName2, which I really don't want to keep doing because this will mess up reports and anything else directly linked to that data field.

Comment: Have you removed the field from the database?

Comment: Yes, I removed it from the table it was added to in the DB. Also, the DB field was set to the correct type that I desired for the field, so it was not interfering with that.

Comment: "the old type still remains assigned to that field" how do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Have you changed the Database Script in project to re-create the column with a new type?

Comment: When attempting to assign data of the new type to the field, I get errors such as "Cannot assign System.int32 to System.string field" or something along those lines. I typically manually edit the field within SQL since I do development locally and have direct access to the SQL server. Should I do it via script instead?

Comment: There's something you had to change which wasn't changed. DAC type needs to be changed and database script and database field type and possibly ASPX editor control type.

Comment: Even if I delete the control in the ASPX, it still gives me the error if the field exists which is odd. I've even deleted old fields, waited awhile, and brought them back to see if it cleared (sometimes it does with time magically) and it still errors. I could show you or send you the project in which this is happening if you'd like to delve into the issue. I've always had this happen any time I change the data type of a custom field extended on a base DAC.

Comment: Deploy to a new instance to test. There's no magic, you probably failed to deploy the changes successfully.

Comment: Do you mean deploy the customization with the incorrect custom field, or delete out the custom field and deploy that to a new instance?

Comment: I mean deploy the final customization on a new instance. If it works the error is in your deployment process. If it doesn't the error is in the customization package.

Comment: In the mean time, if it does successfully deploy and allow me to use the original name without a 2 added on the end, what can you suggest I look for in my deployment process that I might be doing incorrectly to correct the problem on the original project?

Comment: Make sure custom database field was completely removed from database. Publish the project with clean-up option to ensure it re-execute database script. Execute IIS Reset or Restart Application from Apply Updates page in case code was not deployed properly.

Comment: It might be the Restart IIS that I'm missing. I just had the problem creep up with another field I needed to change the value of. I changed it, didn't work. I published with clean up, deleted, re-added the field, double checked XML, published with clean up again, then finally reset the IIS and it worked.

Comment: HB, I've done everything: Changed extended field DAC definition, changed stored DB Script, changed field type in data table in the DB and updated the project, changed project XML file field definition, checked CustObjects table in the DB for the field, and reset IIS. Every time I do a publish with clean up, it changes the definition of the extended field back to an int from nvarchar(30). I'm probably going to submit this to Acumatica to look at in a dev support ticket, but is there anything I left off that check list that could prevent the field from permanently changing in the project?

Comment: I think I found the problem. It looks like the script used to build the actual target table containing the extended field is not being updated when changes are made everywhere else. I don't know if this is a bug or not, but I'm going to submit it to Acumatica to see what they think.

Comment: That would be the 'changed stored DB Script' in your previous comment. You also need to do publish with clean-up to re-execute modified db script.

Comment: I do, but it failed. When I said the changed stored DB Script, I meant the DB Script for defining the field on the screen and/or the DAC, not the script to generate the table. I realize that is confusing. I found I had to change the data table script manually.

Comment: That sounds like the DAC in data access class.. still very hard to identify with so little information.